interchange of integrals and semigroup without the semigroup being an integral operator
In Cazenave's book: BREZIS, HAIM.; CAZENAVE, T. Nonlinear evolution equations. IM-UFRJ, Rio, v. 1, p. 994, 1994. The following corollary appears

The formula (1.5.2) is Duhamel formula:
$$u(t) = T(t)u(0) + \int_0^tT(t-s)f(s)ds$$
Here $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ is the semigroup of contractions generated by $−A$, where $A$ is an m-accretive operator in $X$, with dense domain.
My question is about the observation that is just below the proof, he says that it is possible to demonstrate it directly. I think the proof is straightforward:
\begin{align*}
u(t+s) &= T(t+s)u(0)+ \int_0^{t+s} T(t+s - \sigma) f(\sigma) d\sigma\\
& = T(t)T(s)u(0)+ \int_0^s T(t)T(s - \sigma) f(\sigma) d\sigma + \int_s^{t+s} T(t+s - \sigma) f(\sigma) d\sigma\\
& \mbox{it holds??} = T(t)  \left(T(s)u(0) + \int_0^s T(s - \sigma) f(\sigma) d\sigma \right) + \int_0^{t} T(t - \sigma) f(s+\sigma) d\sigma\\
& = T(t)u(s) + \int_0^{t} T(t - \sigma) f(s+\sigma) d\sigma.\\
\end{align*}
My question is, can we remove the semigroup from within the integral? Apparently this needs to be done in the penultimate step
$$\int_0^s T(t)T(s - \sigma) f(\sigma) d\sigma = T(t) \int_0^s T(s - \sigma) f(\sigma) d\sigma. $$
When the semigroup is an integral operator this is a consequence of Fubinni's Theorem, but in this abstract context is this true?
I'm not sure if that's what is used here, but I've heard that bounded linear operators commute with Bochner integrals, but I never found this result in any book, maybe this will solve this problem, what do you think? This question is relevant, as this result is used to demonstrate the extensibility of solutions to a maximal range. Thanks for any comments.

See for example Theorem 1.19 here: https://ocw.tudelft.nl/wp-content/uploads/Lecture01_01.pdf (it is even true for closed linear operators)

Yes, Bochner integrals commute with bounded linear operators (and even with unbounded closed linear operators, under appropriate assumptions); see for instance Proposition C.4 on page 525 of Engel and Nagel's semigroup book from 2000. "When the semigroup is an integral operator this is a consequence of Fubinni's Theorem" This seems to be a red herring. Even if $T(t)$ is an integral operator, proving this by Fubini's theorem would be quite a technical detour.

Alternatively, see Theorem 1.2.4 on page 15 in the book "Analysis in Banach Spaces, Volume I" (2016) by Hytönen, van Neerven, Veraar, and Weis.

Thank you all for your comments and literature suggestions, they will certainly be useful for my learning!

@JochenGlueck your comment is interesting, even when the semigroup is given by convolution with a kernel could it be incorrect to use Fubinni's Theorem?

I could not find information about this book by Brezis and Cazenave. Could you give a link/reference to this book?

@Akira I really couldn't find any link to the book, I believe it is no longer available.

ok, I sent it to your email.

I have well received the pdf. Thank you very much for your help.
